# ReactJS: Resizing a canvas inside a flexbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm struggling with trying to get a canvas to be dynamically resized to fill the bottom part of a web page when the browser resizes.  The canvas will be resized correctly when increasing the browser window size, but will remain the same size when decreasing the browser window size.

How can I get the canvas to shrink in size along with the browser window?

Here's where I'm at now: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-pare-vk4yb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you set the `canvas`'s height on resize so it can be bigger, but once the canvas' height has been set, its parent can't be shorter.

You can get rid of sets the canvas' height (I'm following your example, I'm not sure how it will affect on the real case) and use a similar approach as `<Container />` and `<FloorPlanWrapper />` - set the parent `display: flex` and the child `flex-grow: 1`.

Like this:

```js
const FloorPlanWrapper = styled.div`
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const StyledCanvas = styled.canvas`
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
`;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-dubinsky-0rzyi

**Notice:** Even though `flexbox` can take care of the canvas **size** it can't take care about the its **resolution**. In order to do so, you need to listen to window resize and update its resolution (`canvas.width = canvas.height * (canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight);`) and then re-render it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-dubinsky-0rzyi

Thanks to https://bob1german.com/2015/03/09/stretching-the-html-5-canvas-fixing-aspect-ratio-problems/ for this formula

Comment: Will this not cause the canvas to stretch without resetting its inner resolution (i.e. drawn items will be stretched also)?

Comment: If the  canvas should has specific ratio, it can be a problem. If not (if its content can be cut) you can re-render on window resize. Anyway, this is another question, I assumed that you take care of it and just ask about how to stretch the canvas element itself, which my answer answers this.

Comment: I disagree..  My question is about resizing a canvas to fit a parent flexbox, not scaling a canvas.  I actually ended up using window resize event to calculate the canvas size from the new window size.  Please include some information about this in your solution, and I'll mark it as the answer.  I think this is important, since I haven't found a suggestion to do this anywhere else.

Comment: Probably I wan't fully understand what you meant. Anyway, I updated the example and my answer to cover that too.